# 二次元配列の各配列内の指定要素をカウントしたい

Tags: python

以下のような二次元配列があります。各配列内に数値が何個あるかカウントしたいのですが、どのようにすればよろしいでしょうか？

もし分かる方がいましたら、ご教示願います。

**対象の二次元配列:**

```
two_array_list = [[0, 0, 0, 'None'], [1, 1, 'None', 'None'], ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None'],['None', 'None', 'None', 'None']]
```

**目的の出力:**

```
[3, 2, 0, 0]

# 又は

3
2
0
0
```

Comment: リストに含まれるのは数値と `'None'`(文字列)だけなのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。数値と文字列のみです。

Answer (score 1):

`int(True) == 1`, `int(False) == 0` である事を利用して `sum()` を取ります。

```py
from numbers import Number

two_array_list = [
  [0, 0, 0, 'None'],
  [1, 1, 'None', 'None'],
  ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None'],
  ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
]

counts = [sum(isinstance(v, Number) for v in a) for a in two_array_list]
print(counts)

#=>
[3, 2, 0, 0]
```

> 私:
> リストに含まれるのは数値と 'None'(文字列)だけなのでしょうか？
>
> hideto.T さん:
> 数値と文字列のみです。

そうなりますと `isinstance()` を使う必要はなく、以下の様にできます。

```py
counts = [sum(v != 'None' for v in a) for a in two_array_list]
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。とてもシンプルで分かりやすいです。
参考にします。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

.countが使えると思います。

例えば、以下の様ではどうですか？

```
two_array_list = [[0, 0, 0, 'None'], [1, 1, 'None', 'None'], ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None'],['None', 'None', 'None', 'None']]

for list in two_array_list:
    n = list.count("None")
    print (len(list) - n)
```

「数値が何個」を数える代わりに、
「Noneが何個」を数えて、その個数を各listから引いた数を計算しています。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。なるほど。そのような考え方があったんですね。とても参考になります。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

こちらの記事とリスト内包表記を応用すれば出来るでしょう。
[count how many of an object type there are in a list Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25355705/9014308)

> ```
> a = [1, 1.23, 'abc', 'ABC', 6.45, 2, 3, 4, 4.98]
>
> sum(isinstance(i, int) for i in a)
> ```

こんな感じになると思います。

```
two_array_list = [[0, 0, 0, 'None'], [1, 1, 'None', 'None'], ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None'],['None', 'None', 'None', 'None']]
result = [sum(isinstance(i, int) for i in a) for a in two_array_list]
print(result)
```

---

その上で、「数値」ということで`int`だけではなく`float`も含む場合はこちらの記事(の解決マークではない最初の方の回答)も適用すれば良いでしょう。
[How to accept the input of both int and float types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43564105/9014308)

> ```
> if isinstance(num, (int, float)):
>     #do stuff
> ```

こんな感じになるでしょう。

```
two_array_list = [[0, 0, 0, 'None'], [1, 2.5, 'None', 'None'], ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None'],['None', 'None', 'None', 'None']]
result = [sum(isinstance(i, (int, float)) for i in a) for a in two_array_list]
print(result)
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。わかりやすい記事とソースコードまでありがとうございます。参考にして今後に活かします。ありがとうございます。